# Force client to obtain ip configuration from one of two wireless networks

Tags: networking

Windows 7, sp1.

This is my simple little home network. Wireless router 1 is hard wired to to cable modem. It supplies ip via dhcp to all my wireless and wired devices. Got extender, for one laptop. However laptop will not let 2nd stronger signal router\extender assign ip config. It insists to get from weaker original wireless router #1.

Have tried ipconfig /release, /flushdns, and rebooted allways attempting quickly to point automated config search to wireless 2 router. Won't take it. Just goes back to wireless one 1.

Don't want to set wireless one to staic ip's.

Is there way to force laptop to obtain ip config from specifc ip configurer (server)?

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: This could be a large number of issues but i'm guessing the most likely col prate to be Wireless Network Priority being set to have `router 1` at a higher priority then `router 2`

---

To change your wireless network priority go `Network and Sharing Center` > `Manage wireless networks` on the left-hand side > Right-click `router 2` > `Move up`

Do this until `router 2` is at the top; power cycle your wireless card

**Further troubleshooting:**

Under properties for `router 1` ticket the check box `Connect to a more preferred network if available` under the connection tab